# I want to create folders through folders upto these many paths

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Too many nosy people around in my home, I want them to get bored tyring to reach these folders, is there a batch file to do that? I am just learning batch files and powershell scripts... Please help.....

"From Downloads"\Regulatory\"Regulatory Affairs"\"European Regulatory Affairs"\Pharmaceuticals\"Over the Counter"\Registrations\Renewal\Variations\"Bulk Variations"\Herbal\"European Herbal Regulatory"\"Good Agricultural Practices Guidelines"\"Good Manufacturing Practices Guidelines"\"Good Clinical Practices"\"Good Laboratory Practices"\"Good Pharmacovigilance Practices"\"Pharmacovigilance Site Master File"\"Herbal Over the Counter"\"Herbal Pharmaceutical Medicines"\Tablets\Capsules\Syrup\Gel\"From Downloads"

Comment: This is a horrible idea. You're going to struggle with the [260 character `MAX_PATH` limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath)

Comment: even if you did manage to do this, a simple search can retrive the content from any subfolder so you might want to think bitlocker \ encryption

Comment: They're just going to wonder why anyone would go to so much trouble to create that atrocity of a directory structure, and be all the more curious for it.

Comment: You could also [hide the file in a picture](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Hide-Files-Inside-Pictures/).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Mathias R Jessen, this is a horrible idea. However, you can create a folder with powershell using the [New-Item cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx). Example:

```
New-Item "c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4" -type directory -force
```